# Creating sitemaps with Codeigniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, generator, sitemap

I would like to know from others' experience the best way to create sitemaps with Codeigniter. I have looked at some plugins/libraries, but all check the database for the pages. What happens if some pages on the site are static and not dynamic?

Is there any way to crawl the site using PHP and creating an XML file with the results?

A tool I have used previously for my projects is http://enarion.net/tools/phpsitemapng/download/

Which is a free tool for creating sitemap and allows functionality such as cron jobs.

What is my next step? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're problem lies in the fact that you have both dynamic and static pages. So, a crawler would work, but you'd have to generate a list of links to all dynamic pages. Then, you're crawler could hit that list and have access to all dynamic pages, and then hit directories where you have your static pages.

However, the docs on the phpsitemapng that you mention state that they will crawl a live website. So, if you have links to all of your pages accessible from those pages, then that will do what you need.

```
Scans files on website (slower, but will also find dynamic generated files and links)
```